# Help needed with first-order logic representation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm very new to first-order logic. I've been working on some tasks below, and would appreciate if somone could check if I have understood and solved the questions correctly

Task:

> Assume that $B$, $F$ and $K$ are relational symbols so that
>
> - $Bx$ interpreted as "$x$ is a biologist
> - $Fx$ interpreted as "$x$ is a philosopher"
> - $Kxy$ interpreted as "$x$ knows $y$"
>
> Assume that $a, b$ and $c$ are constant symbols which represents Aristoteles, Bolzano and Copernicus. Find first-order logic formulas for following sentences:
>
> 1. Aristotle is both a biologist and a philosopher
> 2. All biologists are philosophers
> 3. No philosophers are biologists
> 4. Aristoteles knows a philosopher
> 5. Bolzano knows all philosophers
> 6. Copernicus knows only biologists

Here are my answers:

> 1. There exists one $x$ so that Aristoteles is a $Gx$ and a $Fx$,
>    written as $\exists$$x(Bx(a)$ $\land$ $Fx(a)$
> 2. For all $x$ if $x$ are $Bx$ so $x$ are $Fx$,
>    written as $\forall$$x$$(Bx(x$) $\rightarrow$ $Fx(x)$
> 3. It's not that there is an $x$ such that $x$ are $Fx$ and $x$ are $Bx$,
>    written as $\lnot$$\exists$$x(Fx(x) \land Bx(x)$
> 4. There exists one $x$ such that Aristoteles knows a $Fx$,
>    written as $\exists$$x(Kxy(a, Fx)$
> 5. Not sure
> 6. Not sure

I would appreciate any help and please feel free to correct me if I've done something wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint for 5: We rephrase that to "For all philosophers, Bolzano ______"

Comment: Hint for 6: What does it imply about $x$ if Copernicus knows $x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $(1)$, we do not need a quantifier:

$(1) \quad B(a) \land F(a)$

For $(4)$, we need $\exists x(F(x) \land K(ax))$.

$(5) \quad \forall x(F(x) \rightarrow K(bx))$

$(6) \quad \forall x(\lnot B(x)\rightarrow \lnot K(cx))\equiv \forall x(K(cx) \rightarrow B(x))$. "For all x, if x is not a biologist, then Copernicus does not know x" $\equiv$ "For all x, if Copernicus knows x, then x is a biologist."

Also, be careful with parentheses on $(2), (3)$: you're missing closing parentheses. (Also on $(4)$, but I've included it above.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then I assume $(2)$ and $(3)$ is correct?

Comment: Yes indeed. The English is awkward, but your symbolizations for $(2), (3)$ are spot on, save for the missing parentheses.

Comment: haha, English is not my first language, so I apologize, regarding the $(2)$ question would $\forall$$x$$(Bx(x))$ $\rightarrow$ $Fx(x)$ be more correct? I added 1 more paranthese

Comment: No, it would be $\forall x(B(x) \rightarrow F(x))$

Comment: ah alright, same on the $(3)$ question also?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I saw your double use of x in (2) and (3): B(x): x is a biologist, F(x): x is a philosopher. $(3)\quad \lnot \exists x(F(x) \land B(x))$.

Comment: Yes, because you need to enclose all predicates to show the entire scope of the quantified variable. Otherwise, it's ambiguous.

Comment: Alright, thanks alot for your help, made things clear for me :-) Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, Dabbish! It's wonderful that you regularly post your attempts and show your effort!